# Why jackson @JsonAlias Annotation not work with lombok?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, lombok

When I received JsonFilter object I expected string to be value of string1 or string2
but the value always null.
So why @JsonAlias not work with lombok?

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JsonFilter {

@JsonAlias({"string1", "string2"})
    private String string;

}
```

Lombok dependency

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

By default, lombok doesn’t copy annotations: you must explicitly instruct it to via [`onMethod`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX):

```
@Getter(onMethod=@__({@JsonAlias({"string1", "string2"})}))
private String string;
```

---

I notice there’s a lombok config that might offer a global, and therefore better, fix (I haven’t tried it):

```
lombok.copyableAnnotations = [com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAlias]
```

Comment: Value still null.

Comment: I’ve used onMethod and it works. check your input, your code, that you’re running the code you think you’re running, etc